# non homogeneous heat equation with sine term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve $u_{t}=u_{xx}+\sin(x)$ with $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$ and $u(x,0)=\sin(2x)$

The $\sin(x)$ makes things a bit confusing. I can get the solution for the homogeneous equation ok.
Using separation of variables, we get that $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_k\sin(kx)e^{-k^2t}$

What then is the solution for the non homogeneous case?

Comment: Let $v(x,t)= u(x, t)- sin(x)$  Then $v_{xx}= u_{xx}+ sin(x)$ and $v_t= u_t$.  The equation becomes the homogeneous $v_t= v_{xx}$.  The boundary conditions are $v(0,t)= v(\pi,t)= 0$.  The initial condition is $v(x, 0)= u(x, 0)- sin(x)= sin(2x)- sin(x)$.

Comment: thats very cool. how did you see that. I see it now but still.

Comment: I saw that "sin(x)" was the problem so I thought about how to get rid of it!

Answer (score 3):

By changing the dependent variable $u$ to a new dependent variable $v$ by the substitution $ u(x,t) = v(x,t) + \phi (x) $, the original problem can be reduced to two decoupled ones: precisely, by using  we have that
$$ 
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \phi '(x), \\ 
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \phi ''(x), \\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}.
\end{split} 
$$
and then
$$ 
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \phi ''(x) +\sin(x)
$$
Now we need to find the solutions of $ \phi ''(x) +\sin(x) = 0 \ $ in order to solve the former mixed problem: precisely we need to solve the following simple ODE boundary vaule problem
$$ 
\begin{cases}
\phi ''(x) + \sin(x) = 0 \ , \\ 
\phi(0) = 0, \\ 
\phi(\pi)=0,
\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{ODE}
$$
From the knowledge of solutions of \eqref{1}, we obtain the mixed boundary initial conditions for the following homogeneous problem
$$ 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} \\ 
v(0,t)=u(0,t) - \phi(0) = 0 , \\ 
v(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)-\phi(\pi)=0 \\
v(x,0)=u(x,0)-\phi(x)
\end{cases}
$$
which we can solve by using the Fourier series approach.